# What happens if I use .htaccess of network multisite on a single site installation?

Tags: multisite, htaccess

If I use the .htaccess code given in network setup (subfolder version) on a single site installation, what problems could occur? I am testing this for a project so It's not pointless.

I tested and I can't have posts with permalink like `/2019/10/07/wp-admin/`. But that's not important.

this is the single site .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

this is the network(subfolder version) .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: "I am testing this for a project" - What functionality is it that you require?

Comment: @MrWhite I have a wordpress installation and I want to load it between network and single site based on some conditions, it would be great if I can have a fixed htaccess file. so I can manage those conditions only via php.